# Convergence of Taylor series expansion

Tags: limits, power-series, laurent-series

The Taylor series expansion of $\frac{1}{(x^2 -1)^2}$ at $x=-1$ is given by

$\frac{1}{(x^2 -1)^2} =\frac{1}{4(x+1)^{2}}+\frac{1}{4(x+1)}$+$\frac{3}{16}$+$\frac{(x+1)}{8}$ $\ldots$

Is this series convergent? If so, how do I prove it?

Comment: Do you mean your expansion is a Laurent series? Because a taylor series around $x=-1$ would only have maybe a constant and *positive* powers of $x+1$ in it.

Comment: Hi @coffeemath  I hope you are doing well. In fact, I mean the taylor series, since the problem that I have considers $f(x)=1/(x^{2}-1)^{2}$ as real function.

Comment: Taylor series around a point is only for functions analytic in some neighborhood of that point. But $f(x)=1/(x^2-1)^2$ is not analytic around $x=1$ in fact has a pole there.

Comment: hi @coffeemath. So, must I consider $f(x)$ as a  complex function?

Comment: It is also a function of the real variable $x$ --- one can replace the real variable $x$ by the letter $z$ which could denote a complex number, that's one way "poles" are thought of. This happens for very simple functions also, for example $f(x)=x^2$ is a very standard real variable function one sees much of in Calc I, which near the beginning of complex analysis is looked at as a function $f(z)=z^2$ where now the letter $z$ is viewed as meaning a complex number. A lot of functions have this double interpretation, such as $\sin(x)$ versus $\sin(z).$

Comment: @coffeemath.I don't know if I have gotten your point. Does the Laurent series of $f(x)$ remains valid even if $f$ is a real function?

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

To find the Laurent series at $z=-1$, note that
$$
\frac{1}{(z^2-1)^2}=
\frac14
\left(\frac{1}{(z+1)^2}
+\frac{1}{(z+1)}
-\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}
\right)
$$

So you need to work with the last two terms.

$$
\frac{1}{z-1}=\frac{1}{z+1-2}=-\frac12\frac{1}{1-\frac{z+1}{2}}
$$

You can then find a series for $z$ with $|z+1|<2$. Taking the derivative term by term, you can find the series for $\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}$